# ConsumerManager.verify() fails with "No service element found to match the ClaimedID / OP-endpoint in the assertion."

Tags: jsf, openid, stackexchange, openid4java

i am trying to implement openid authentication in a JSF2 application and everything seems to be working fine until the moment where the application needs to verify the openid-server's response (in my case stackexchange).

i have already checked out the openid4java source to debug and track the problem down but i cannot seem to find the reason why it fails. the code is based on the [example code](http://code.google.com/p/openid4java/wiki/SampleConsumer) from the openid4java website.

first i am crafting a request like this:

```
    if (getManager() == null) {
        setManager(new ConsumerManager());
    }
    try {
        // perform discovery on the user-supplied identifier
        List discoveries = getManager().discover(getOpenIdIdentifier());

        // attempt to associate with the OpenID provider
        // and retrieve one service endpoint for authentication
        DiscoveryInformation discovered = getManager().associate(discoveries);

        // store the discovery information in the user's session for later use
        // leave out for stateless operation / if there is no session
        ((HttpSession) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSession(false)).setAttribute("discovered", discovered);

        // obtain a AuthRequest message to be sent to the OpenID provider
        AuthRequest authReq = getManager().authenticate(discovered, RETURN_URL);
        FetchRequest fetch = FetchRequest.createFetchRequest();
        fetch.addAttribute("email", "http://schema.openid.net/contact/email", true);
        // attach the extension to the authentication request
        authReq.addExtension(fetch);

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(authReq.getDestinationUrl(true));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am being redirected to https://openid.stackexchange.com/, i use my email & pw to log in and stackexchange redirects me back to RETURN_URL where the following servlet is waiting:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    User u = ((User) request.getSession().getAttribute("user"));
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    // extract the parameters from the authentication response
    // (which comes in as a HTTP request from the OpenID provider)
    ParameterList openidResp = new ParameterList(request.getParameterMap());

    // retrieve the previously stored discovery information
    DiscoveryInformation discovered = (DiscoveryInformation) request.getSession().getAttribute("discovered");
    // extract the receiving URL from the HTTP request
    StringBuffer receivingURL = request.getRequestURL();
    String queryString = request.getQueryString();
    if (queryString != null && queryString.length() > 0) {
        receivingURL.append("?").append(request.getQueryString());
    }

    // verify the response
    try {
        VerificationResult verification = u.getManager().verify(receivingURL.toString(), openidResp, discovered); // here is where ERROR ConsumerManager:1740 - No service element found to match the ClaimedID / OP-endpoint in the assertion. happens

        Identifier verifiedId = verification.getVerifiedId();

            if (verifiedId != null) {// success, use the verified identifier to identify the user
            AuthSuccess authSuccess = (AuthSuccess) verification.getAuthResponse();

            if (authSuccess.hasExtension(AxMessage.OPENID_NS_AX)) {
                FetchResponse fetchResp = (FetchResponse) authSuccess.getExtension(AxMessage.OPENID_NS_AX);

                String email = (String) fetchResp.getAttributeValues("email").get(0);
                u.autoAuthByEmail(email);
                response.sendRedirect("/");
            }


        } else {// OpenID authentication failed
            u.setLoggedIn(false);
            response.getOutputStream().print("auth failed. <a href=\"/\">home</a>");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

here is what i get in the server.log (RETURN_URL replaced with mydomain.org):

```
[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.117+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,116  INFO Discovery:143 - Starting discovery on URL identifier: https://openid.stackexchange.com/|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.119+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,119  INFO HttpCache:316 - Returning cached HEAD response for https://openid.stackexchange.com/|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.121+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,120  INFO HttpCache:117 - Returning cached GET response for https://openid.stackexchange.com/xrds|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.145+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,145  INFO YadisResolver:264 - Yadis discovered 1 endpoints from: https://openid.stackexchange.com/|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.147+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,147  INFO Discovery:164 - Discovered 1 OpenID endpoints.|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.149+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,148  INFO ConsumerManager:705 - Trying to associate with https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider attempts left: 4|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.152+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,151  INFO ConsumerManager:714 - Found an existing association: {634581615862250013}{M+QESA==}{32}|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.154+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,153  INFO ConsumerManager:1063 - Creating authentication request for OP-endpoint: https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider claimedID: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select OP-specific ID: http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.156+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,155  INFO RealmVerifier:282 - Return URL: http://mydomain.org/openid matches realm: http://mydomain.org/openid|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.679+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,679  INFO ConsumerManager:1121 - Verifying authentication response...|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.680+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,680  INFO ConsumerManager:1145 - Received positive auth response.|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.681+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,681  INFO Discovery:143 - Starting discovery on URL identifier: https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/2d34c1da-cca8-4095-83be-eee02722879b|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.682+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,682  INFO HttpCache:316 - Returning cached HEAD response for https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/2d34c1da-cca8-4095-83be-eee02722879b|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.683+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,682  INFO HttpCache:117 - Returning cached GET response for https://openid.stackexchange.com/xrds|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.704+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,704  INFO YadisResolver:264 - Yadis discovered 1 endpoints from: https://openid.stackexchange.com/user/2d34c1da-cca8-4095-83be-eee02722879b|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.706+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,706  INFO Discovery:164 - Discovered 1 OpenID endpoints.|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.707+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,707 ERROR ConsumerManager:1740 - No service element found to match the ClaimedID / OP-endpoint in the assertion.|#]

[#|2011-11-29T12:20:16.709+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=46;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|12:20:16,708 ERROR ConsumerManager:1164 - Discovered information verification failed.|#]
```

i have verified that

- getManager() on the sending and the receiving part is the same object
- the sessionId on both parts is identical

i have been fighting with this problem for 2 days now and i seem to be stuck. i would be very thankful for any pointers.

EDIT:

i just tested the same code with an openid account at myopenid.com and there it works. i am really confused about what the problem is now :|

Comment: [OpenID](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/307647/) is deprecated, so I'm voting to close this post as non-reproducible.